# Запуск скрипта на опенсервере

Tags: php, mysql, openserver

Как запустить скрипт?

написала скрипт в планировщике задач, назначила ближайшее время, не выполнился... результат выполнения скрипта не написалось в text.txt (файл text.txt вообще не создался и не написал результат в себя ("hello world"))

```
%progdir%\modules\php\%phpdriver%\php-win.exe -c %progdir%\userdata\temp\config\php.ini -q -f %sitedir%\site.loc\hello.php -O %progdir%\userdata\temp\temp.txt
```

Это пробный скрипт hello.php.
Вопрос. Как нужно сделать, чтобы результат выполнения скрипта записался в лог?
2)Дайте мне, плиз, документацию, по

```
-c,-q,-f, -O
```

Гуглила на эту тему, не нашла... Какой запрос вбить в поисковике? 
3)Моя основная задача это сделать выборки из других таблиц и занести в одну. Скажу, что таблица , из которой делается выборка, большая, содержит 46549259 строк. И скрипт, наверное, будет выполнятся 3 дня... На что обратить внимание, и как его запустить, и чтобы результат занесения скрипта заносился в файл? Я попробовала запустить скрипт hello.php(см. выше), у меня не получилось(см. выше) или я что-то неправильно делаю?

Comment: постарайтесь ограничиваться одной проблемой на вопрос: (1) получается ли у вас запустить хоть какую-нибудь программу через планировщик? (2) получается ли у вас запустить самый простой php-скрипт, который (для отладки) создаёт файл прямо внутри скрипта с фиксированным путём и сбрасывает туда все значения используемых в команде из вопроса переменных окружения, не используя переменных окружений в этом тесте и не используя опций для php-win? (3) что происходит, если ручками запусить команду из командной строки (сообщение об ошибке, возвращаемый код)?

Comment: 1) Я попробовала запустить hello.php,внутри которого есть код "echo hello". По идее мой обработчик должен был создать файл и сунуть туда "hello". 3) если ручками запустить команду то все работает

Comment: код такой в планировщике